# Kaa Project : ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader and other error

Tags: server, kaa

I follow the steps from 
https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/

The last command is

```
$ cat /var/log/kaa/* | grep ERROR
```

and the error occur

> 2560-07-13 16:20:00,333 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   2560-07-13 16:25:59,019 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   2560-07-13 16:37:41,610 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   2560-07-13 17:01:49,474 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   2560-07-13 18:26:42,078 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   2560-07-13 18:27:31,562 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
>   2560-07-13 19:04:39,818 [qtp1591550320-71] ERROR org.spring4gwt.server.RpcHelper - Unexpected exception occured while invoking service method - createKaaAdmin
>   2560-07-14 10:26:03,480 [main] ERROR o.k.k.s.n.s.i.KaaNodeInitializationService - Failed to connect to Zookeeper within 5 minutes. Kaa Node Server will be stopped.

I reinstalled all again but it doesn't work. The last error, I already started Zookeeper but the error still occurs.